# Render table element with colspan in Reagent

Tags: html, clojure, clojurescript, reagent, hiccup

I have a table in reagent and have set the col-span of a table header = 2.

```
 (defn my-table []
  [:table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
   [:thead
    [:tr
     [:th "Col1"]
     [:th "Col2"]
     (doall (for [id @ids]
          ^{:key id}
          [:th {:data-id (id :id)
                :col-span "2"}
           (str (get id :name))]))]]
   [:tbody
    (doall (for [i (range (count @table-items))]
         (let [table-item (cursor table-items [i])]
           ^{:key i}
           [item-row table-item])))]])
```

But in each row, see `item-row` below, I am looping through a data structure to grab the data for the split column in that row and am having issues.  I can get the data to render properly if do

```
[:div [:td [:span (:id id)]]
             [:td [:span (:name id)]]]
```

which I know is incorrect/invalid html.

```
 (defn item-row [item]
    (fn []
      [:tr
       [:td [:span (:key1 @item)]]
       [:td [:span (:key2 @item)]]
       (doall (for [id @ids]
            ^{:key id}
            [[:td [:span (:x id)]]
             [:td [:span (:y id)]]]))]))
```

Does anyone have an idea on how render two `:td` elements in the for loop?  My thought was to wrap the two `:td` elements in a vector and let reagent handle rendering the split columns.

```
 (doall (for [id @ids]
            ^{:key id}
            [[:td [:span (:x id)]]
             [:td [:span (:y id)]]])
```

I also get the following error:
`core.cljs:4793 Uncaught Error: No item [:td "."] in vector of length 2
    at Object.cljs$core$vector_index_out_of_bounds [as 
    vector_index_out_of_bounds]`

which is correlated to `[:td [:span (:y id)]]`

Comment: What isn't working the way you expect?  Are you saying the HTML you're producing is invalid?

Comment: I updated my question to add more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that you are just returning data, so one way to do this is just build up the initial contents of the `:tr` vector with those first two columns and then add the rest of the `:td` elements in using `into`.  Here's an example that I think will solve your problem:

```
cljs.user=> (def ids [{:x 1 :y 2} {:x 3 :y 4}])
#'cljs.user/ids
cljs.user=> (let [tr [:tr 
       #_=>           [:td "first col"]
       #_=>           [:td "second col"]]]
       #_=>   (reduce (fn [acc id]
       #_=>             (into acc
       #_=>                   [[:td [:span (:x id)]]
       #_=>                    [:td [:span (:y id)]]]))
       #_=>           tr
       #_=>           ids))
[:tr [:td "first col"] [:td "second col"] [:td [:span 1]] [:td [:span 2]] [:td [:span 3]] [:td [:span 4]]]
cljs.user=>
```

Comment: Works great and I understand it, but I am curious as to why my approach using ``for`` does not work?

Comment: You would need another step with `for` because `for` constructs a sequence with one element for each `id`, but you want two elements for each `id`.  So you need to take the output from `for` and then maybe do something with `map` and `into` to flatten out the paired `td` elements.